# extract stdout_lines of ansible variable to csv file, each stdout_lines has multiple lines

Tags: linux, ansible

Command 1 output

```
DATA            EXTERN      30708      27086   CONNECTED
DATA01          NORMAL      10228      10120   CONNECTED
DATA02          HIGH        15342      15180   MOUNTED
```

Command 2 Instace FRC command output

```
" 3 3db02abc7. DATA01 DATA011 READ WRITE ALLOWED 01/09/2021 12:37:51 PM", 
" 2 3db02abc9. DATA02 DATA01db2 READ WRITE ALLOWED 05/07/2021 02:18:22 PM"
" 3 3db02abc8. DATA01 DATA011 READ WRITE ALLOWED 01/09/2021 12:37:51 PM", 
" 2 3db02abc0. DATA02 DATA01db2 READ WRITE ALLOWED 05/07/2021 02:18:22 PM"
```

Command 3 Instace FRC command output

```
$ ps -ef | grep pmon | grep -v grep | awk '{ print $8 }' | cut -d '_' -f3
+ASM
S112
```

Above is the sample output of stdout_lines in ansible, I want to write this output to csv file column wise , entire command1 under column 1, command2 under column 2, command3 under column 3. or else write each command output inside single cell of csv file?

I tried using lineinfile with and without insertafter, its getting extracted to csv file next to next column. How can I write the output to csvfile same as stdout_lines.

Comment: So the result should be a one line csv file with each command result being pasted to its own cell (3 in total) as a multi line content? Else please clarify your question.

Comment: Yes, thats correct Zeitounator, i need entire command1 under single column1 and command2 under column 2 and so on.

Comment: I really wish that `ps | grep | grep -v | awk` nonsense would just die.   use `ps h -o cmd -C pmon` instead.   or, sometimes (when you need to use a regex to match the process): `ps h -p $(pgrep -f pmon) -o cmd`.

Comment: correction: that second form should be `ps h -o cmd -p $(pgrep -f pmon)`

Comment: Hi Cas, my concern is not to correct the command, its an exanmple i have given, i am looking how to add the cmd outputs to column wise in a file